# how to hide specific wireless network?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Not sure if this is desktop-specific, if it is, my is kde.
There are multiple wifi networks at home or at work, which I do not even posses password to and/or I don't want to use them. Ever. I don't want to see them in very long list of wireless networks to connect to. How to hide them?

Answer (score 0):

Clean network manager connections for all "never" connected:

```
for i in `nmcli c | grep "never" | grep -o -- "[0-9a-fA-F]\{8\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{12\}"` ; do nmcli connection delete uuid $i ; done
```

Do `nmcli connection` before and after to see the difference.

1 issue: those network connections will return. To redo the command put it in a script and execute it every so often. `/etc/crontab`,  every 10 minutes or so might be a good option; do use absolute paths (`/usr/bin/nmcli`)

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, I didn't know this command. However, it does not show any wifi I didn't used before. `nmcli device wifi list` shows all wifis the gui applet shows, but `nmcli connection` does show only the ones I connected to before